Adding many animations from seperate armatures onto a resting armature
I've made some progress, I used this script from 2 same rigs, different poses, but animation acts weird when trying to merge all into 1 rig
    import bpy

# Get references to the 'Armature' and 'TPose' armatures
ARMATURE_SOURCE = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
ARMATURE_TARGET = bpy.context.active_object

# Initialize a count for bones with no equivalents
no_equivalent_count = 0

# Loop through all bones in 'ARMATURE_TARGET' armature
for bone in ARMATURE_TARGET.pose.bones:
    # Check if there's a bone with the same name in 'ARMATURE_SOURCE'
    if bone.name in ARMATURE_SOURCE.pose.bones:
        # Remove all constraints from the bone to avoid redundance and potential issues:
        for constraint in bone.constraints:
            bone.constraints.remove(constraint)
        
        # Create a Copy Transforms constraint and set the target bone
        constraint = bone.constraints.new(type='COPY_TRANSFORMS')
        constraint.target = ARMATURE_SOURCE
        constraint.subtarget = bone.name  # Use the same bone name as the target
        print(f"Constrained '{bone.name}' to its equivalent in '{ARMATURE_SOURCE.name}'.")
    else:
        # If no equivalent bone is found, print a message and increment the count
        print(f"No equivalent bone found for '{bone.name}' in '{ARMATURE_SOURCE.name}'.")
        no_equivalent_count += 1

# Print the count of bones with no equivalents
if no_equivalent_count <= 1:
    print(f"Number of bones with no equivalents: {no_equivalent_count}")

Long story short all of the animations have different resting poses so I need to iterate through the bones and adjust them.
That works for one animation, but I can't add any other ones, they just keep overwriting each other.
When I go to just do them one by one, I cant delete the animation rig because it messes up the rested armature.
I'm not too experienced in blender so if someone could give me advice on how they would approach this problem.
The dope sheet and action editor is confusing.
